# MVC 5 Owin CAS Logoff action doesn't log off

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, cas

I'm trying to implement [noelbundick's CAS authentication for Owin](https://github.com/noelbundick/Owin.Security.CAS) in my MVC 5 application, but with a twist. We want this to be the only way you can log in or out, so we started the application with no authentication, and used [this tutorial](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/) to set up all the authentication, also using another new solution with the built-in external authentication just as a way to compare what I'm doing.

So I've switched out all the google stuff with CAS stuff, and everything works great, except for some reason, the logout button doesn't work. Specifically, the action here

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

seems to skip over the `SignOut()` function, and go straight to the `RedirectToAction()`. I'll give you some more code that may help, but I'm really not sure what else could help. The references in the first paragraph have all the code that I've used, along with any default code from whatever Visual Studio gives you on a basic MVC site with external authentication.

Authentication manager:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    };
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);
    CasAuthenticationOptions casOptions = new CasAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CasServerUrlBase = "https://cas.ourserver.com/cas"
    };
    app.UseCasAuthentication(casOptions);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

ChallengeResult:

```
private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
    }
     public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
     public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
     public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
            .Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

To be clear, I don't need it to log off of the CAS server, just the website. It's fine if the CAS cookie remains. The problem is that it still says "Welcome, User!" and "Log off" at the top.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can give you that would help. I've googled everything and can't find a solution online or on StackOverflow, but that may be because I didn't google the correct terms as well, so that's also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying a million different solutions, and on my current code I had

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(
    //  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
    //  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    //Session.Abandon();
    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```

When I changed it back to the original LogOff action above, it worked all of the sudden. Sorry!